# What am I missing to use the Processing opengl library when invoking from the command line?

Tags: java, processing

I've got a sketch pulled from [here](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/opengl/):

```
import processing.opengl.*;

float a; 

void setup() {
  size(800, 600, OPENGL);
  fill(0, 153);
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotateX(a);
  rotateY(a*2);
  rect(-200, -200, 400, 400);
  rotateX(PI/2);
  rect(-200, -200, 400, 400);
  a += 0.01;
}
```

When I run this sketch from the Processing IDE it works fine. Trying to run it from the command-line, less so:

```
$ /home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/java/bin/java -classpath "/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/java/lib/rt.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/java/lib/tools.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/lib/antlr.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/lib/core.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/lib/ecj.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/lib/jna.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/lib/pde.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/libraries/opengl/library/opengl.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/libraries/opengl/library/jogl.jar:/home/blt/projects/processing-1.2.1/libraries/opengl/library/gluegen-rt.jar" processing.app.Commander --sketch="/home/blt/sketchbook/sketch_mar18a/" --output="/home/blt/sketchbook/sketch_mar18a/output" --run
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.app.Sketch.preprocess(Sketch.java:1381)
    at processing.app.Sketch.preprocess(Sketch.java:1205)
    at processing.app.Sketch.build(Sketch.java:1568)
    at processing.app.Commander.<init>(Commander.java:206)
    at processing.app.Commander.main(Commander.java:97)
```

Please note that at the end of the classpath there I've included all of the jars mentioned in `libraries/opengl/library/export.txt`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a bug](http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=373).

Comment: Seems to be present in 1.5.1. Wow, processing has some _really_ old open bugs. Any idea for a work-around?

Comment: I'm not _really_ into processing ;) The last commenter pointed out that there is no workaround, and the original issue traces back to 1.2.1. You could have a crack at the 2.0 alpha version, though. Good luck!